# Compilation problem with LocalDate attributes in Java?

Tags: java, compilation, attributes, localdate

I'm struggling to solve a problem in my code. In my classes, I have an attributes that are dates. When I try to compile my program, the errors say that it cannot find the symbol, with an arrow under the L on local date? I'm unsure how to proceed? Thankss

```
public class Adventure{
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    public void Setdate(int year, int month, int day){
        this.startDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    }
    public LocalDate getStartDate(){
        return startDate;
    }
    public void SetDuration(int duration){
        this.duration = duration;
        endDate = startDate.plusDate(duration * 7);
    }
    public int getDuration(){
        return duration;
    }
    public LocalDate getEndDate(){
        return endDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you imported Java.time.LocalDate?

Comment: I'll ask this now because often enough it comes down to it: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: try to clean your project and also delete the project from your IDE and then reimport it.

Comment: Yep, did nothing

Comment: I'm using VS code, i'm unsure what you mean by clean it up and delete it from the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have imported `java.time.LocalDate` and it still doesn't compile you are most using Java 7 or earlier. `java.time` was introduced in Java 8 as part of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

There is however [a backport library for earlier Java versions](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
 that you can add to your project.

Comment: seems odd to me though, because i've used it in other projects before this. I'll fiddle around with my code. There could be other problems